# iFrame doesn't scroll when using tab key on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a web application which is embedded inside an iFrame. For one of our HTML page we have lots of textboxes, and the content is quite big, so that one has to scroll down to navigate through the content. When we navigate through the textboxes by using the tab key, the iFrame doesn't scroll if the textbox is present somewhere in the middle of the page, which can be seen through scrolling via mouse. Please note that, the focus on textbox is there. 
This issue is only occurring chrome, it works fine in Firefox and IE11.
There is one thread on code.google.com in chromium section where there is mentioned of this issue, but still no solution has been found. [Issue Link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444948)
The sample code to replicate the issue is here [Sample Code](http://1drv.ms/1AiqkdU)

Comment: The issue link says it's a bug in Chrome (starting with v39). So what are you hoping for with this question? The answer is, it's a bug. Wait until it's resolved. By the way, your link to the sample code is dead.

Comment: @Mr Lister : I have updated the link, now you might be able to download. I wanted to know is there any way via javascript or jquery that I can make the scroll work on press of the tab. If that can happen that will be a big solution and help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues gets fixed in the lastest version of Chrome ie 43.0 and higher. In anycase try the below jquery.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('input').focus(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 50
            }, 20);
         });
      });
   </script>
</head>
```