# Google Chrome scrolling makes Tab completely unresponsive

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have used overflow scroll in one of my div in my project,So when I am doing scrolling through scroll-button of mouse and drag it to left or right .It is making a whole tab unresponsive ,even when I reload page it is still unresponsive but working f9 with new Tab again. which means it makes only a tab unresponsive while app is working corrently.

As I am new please give some suggestions or guide me.

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Comment: Is this a similar problem to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317349/iframe-doesnt-scroll-when-using-tab-key-on-chrome ?